# Getting custom post type info using get_adjacent_post

Tags: custom-post-types, query-posts

This is an example of how I'm grabbing images from my custom post type now, using `query_posts();`

```
// query_posts stuff made up here.
$my_array = get_custom_field('image:to_array', 'to_image_array'); 
// $my_array is now all my images from that post.
```

What I want to do is pull out an image from a custom post type using get_adjacent_post(). When I print out the adjacent post's info, I don't see anything useful for pulling out my images from this post type. Here is a print_r of the adjacent post.

```
(
    [ID] => 185
    [post_author] => 1
    [post_date] => 2012-04-11 18:51:22
    [post_date_gmt] => 2012-04-11 18:51:22
    [post_content] => content
    [post_title] => the title
    [post_excerpt] => 
    [post_status] => publish
    [comment_status] => open
    [ping_status] => closed
    [post_password] => 
    [post_name] => the-title
    [to_ping] => 
    [pinged] => 
    [post_modified] => 2012-04-12 17:37:49
    [post_modified_gmt] => 2012-04-12 17:37:49
    [post_content_filtered] => 
    [post_parent] => 0
    [guid] => http://thewebsite.com/?post_type=photo_group&#038;p=185
    [menu_order] => 0
    [post_type] => photo_group
    [post_mime_type] => 
    [comment_count] => 0
)
```

Is there a way to pull out my custom post type's images this way?

Answer (score 1):

`get_custom_field` is not a standard wordpress function, unless given the source code we cannot help you with it.

But I can tell you, that it is not getting its data from the post object, but the post meta.

e.g.

```
$value = get_post_meta($post->ID,'key name',true); // where true indicates there is only a single key value pair of 'key name'
```

Answer (score 0):

`get_post_meta` can help you as well. Use this way

```
global $wp_query;

$postid = $wp_query->post->ID;

echo get_post_meta($postid, 'key', true);
```